# Namenode format and starting the namenode in hadoop2.2.0

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to install Single node configuration, I succeeded to certain point like downloading and unzipping the tar and editing all the configuration files, but faced problems when formatting the namenode.

The errors are:

```
14/07/14 02:56:40 WARN fs.FileUtil: Failed to delete file or dir [/home/renu123/yarn/yarn_data/hdfs/namenode/current/seen_txid]: it still exists.
14/07/14 02:56:40 WARN fs.FileUtil: Failed to delete file or dir [/home/renu123/yarn/yarn_data/hdfs/namenode/current/VERSION]: it still exists.
14/07/14 02:56:40 WARN fs.FileUtil: Failed to delete file or dir [/home/renu123/yarn/yarn_data/hdfs/namenode/current/fsimage_0000000000000000000]: it still exists.
14/07/14 02:56:40 WARN fs.FileUtil: Failed to delete file or dir [/home/renu123/yarn/yarn_data/hdfs/namenode/current/fsimage_0000000000000000000.md5]: it still exists.
14/07/14 02:56:40 FATAL namenode.NameNode: Exception in namenode join
java.io.IOException: Cannot remove current directory: /home/renu123/yarn/yarn_data/hdfs/namenode/current
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.clearDirectory(Storage.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:523)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:544)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:837)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1320)
14/07/14 02:56:40 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
14/07/14 02:56:40 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at ubuntu/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

After searching on google I formatted namenode by switching to root account as below:

```
root@ubuntu:~/yarn/yarn_data/hdfs/namenode# hdfs namenode -format
Re-format filesystem in Storage Directory /home/renu123/yarn/yarn_data/hdfs/namenode ? (Y or N) Y
14/07/14 02:59:30 INFO common.Storage: Storage directory /home/renu123/yarn/yarn_data/hdfs/namenode has been successfully formatted.
14/07/14 02:59:30 INFO namenode.FSImage: Saving image file /home/renu123/yarn/yarn_data/hdfs/namenode/current/fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000000000 using no compression
14/07/14 02:59:30 INFO namenode.FSImage: Image file /home/renu123/yarn/yarn_data/hdfs/namenode/current/fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000000000 of size 196 bytes saved in 0 seconds.
14/07/14 02:59:30 INFO namenode.NNStorageRetentionManager: Going to retain 1 images with txid >= 0
14/07/14 02:59:30 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 0
14/07/14 02:59:30 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at ubuntu/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

Even after formatting still I can see the directories in `hdfs/namenode` folder i.e current

Assuming the namenode is formatted I proceeded further and tried to start namenode using the command `start-dfs.sh`, but wasn't able to.

This is the log take out from `usr/local/hadoop/logs`:

```
2014-07-14 02:49:10,478 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Cannot access storage directory /home/renu123/yarn/yarn_data/hdfs/namenode
2014-07-14 02:49:10,484 INFO org.mortbay.log: Stopped SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:50070
2014-07-14 02:49:10,585 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping NameNode metrics system...
2014-07-14 02:49:10,585 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system stopped.
2014-07-14 02:49:10,586 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system shutdown complete.
2014-07-14 02:49:10,587 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Exception in namenode join
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /home/renu123/yarn/yarn_data/hdfs/namenode is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverStorageDirs(FSImage.java:292)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:568)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:443)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:684)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1320)
2014-07-14 02:49:10,590 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
2014-07-14 02:49:10,602 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

Help me find the solution to this.

My configuration files are

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
   <name>fs.default.name</name>

   <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-ste.xml

```
<configuration>
<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>

   <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>

   <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
   <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>

   <value>yarn</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
   <name>dfs.replication</name>

   <value>1</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>

   <value>file:/home/renu123/yarn/yarn_data/hdfs/namenode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>

   <value>file:/home/renu123/yarn/yarn_data/hdfs/datanode</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you update please with your configuration files? It seems like your resource manager isn't making the node fail

Comment: If you couldn't edit your configuration files how did you configure your cluster then?

Comment: I said i am not able to edit the question with configuration files.but Parto edited my question with good format. now u can see the exact question if u know the solution plz provide thanks

Comment: Finally i am able to complete the installation of hadoop in my machine , mistake i have done is namenode format is incorrect.solution is to give proper file permissions to hadoop installation folder.Command used for this is                  sudo chown -R hduser:hadoop hadoop

Comment: It is a very common problem. Hadoop fails are usually related to permissions and configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

there may be  a problem due to file keyword you have used in

```
<configuration>
<property>
   <name>dfs.replication</name>

   <value>1</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>

   **<value>file:/home/renu123/yarn/yarn_data/hdfs/namenode</value>**
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>

   **<value>file:/home/renu123/yarn/yarn_data/hdfs/datanode</value>**
 </property>
</configuration>
```

you may need to remove this **"file:"** and specify as below

```
/home/renu123/yarn/yarn_data/hdfs/namenode
```

and

```
/home/renu123/yarn/yarn_data/hdfs/datanode
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but it did not worked.I removed file: from the configuration file and tried to start namenode same error i got.

Comment: I followed 'https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-hadoop-on-ubuntu-13-10' URL to set up my Hadoop environment

Comment: @Renukeswar link is not working and it must be the issue of rights if not of the file

Answer (score 0):

@Renukeshwar, I had the same problem.
If you look at these lines in your error logs,

```
java.io.IOException:Cannot remove directory:/home/renu123/yarn/yarn_data/hdfs/namenode/current
java.io.IOException: Cannot create directory: /home/renu123/yarn/yarn_data/hdfs/namenode/current
```

This happens when the current user does not have read and write access to that folder.

#### Solution

After changing all the configurations in all .xml files, type this in terminal.
This gives the user `hduser` of group `hadoop` access to the folder.

```
sudo chown -R hduser:hadoop /usr/local/hadoop
```

Note:
To check which group user belongs, type `groups your-username-here`

Edit: you may have to remove tmp directories.

```
sudo rm -R /path-to-your-common-storage
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed the installation steps given in link (@Vikas Hardia - Link is working just ignore appended ' at last - Might be typo :)  - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-hadoop-on-ubuntu-13-10)

Then below should work for you.

Solution

```
sudo chown -R hduser:hadoop /usr/local/hadoop
sudo chown -R hduser:hadoop /usr/local/hadoop_store
```

This has worked for me, If any issue just make sure you have changed `.bashrc` file for your *hadoop-user* properly.

Answer (score 0):

Format the namenode using

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

Further reading: https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GettingStartedWithHadoop#Formatting_the_Namenode